# How to find all the books in which a given essay is published?

Tags: publications

It is fairly common for a journal article in humanities to be published afterwards in a book by the same author or in some collection edited by someone else.

Is there an easy way to track where a given paper was published *afterwards*? That is, is it possible to find all the books where a given paper was republished?

This is relevant because sometimes the article can have minor (or sometimes pretty major) edits when republished in a book, or have some other related texts there (e.g., replies, other papers on the same subject, or a newer essay by the same author side by side)